# Hubot integration with Slack

Tags: slack, hubot

I am trying to integrate Hubot with Slack and followed the steps [as mentioned here](http://slackapi.github.io/hubot-slack/), however I am not getting any connectivity message. There is no error as well. What could have caused this behavior?

```
PS C:\Users\myuserid\Projects\mybots> bin/hubot -a slack
npm WARN hubot-help@0.2.2 requires a peer of coffee-script@^1.12.6 but none was installed.

up to date in 2.764s
warn: SlackDataStore is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. See project documentation for a migration guide.
warn: SlackDataStore is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. See project documentation for a migration guide.
```

Comment: I don't think that is your problem as neither of those messages should cause the bot connect to fail. They're both npm warnings, which can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I think you missed API token key in the run command. The command should be.

```
HUBOT_SLACK_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ./bin/hubot --adapter slack
```

If it went well, you would see a message like this.

```
 INFO Connected to Slack RTM
```

You may follow [this well explained tutorial](https://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/integrate-hubot-with-slack-to-create-efficient-chatbot/) to integrate Hubot with Slack.